# Различные версии IOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios

```
У меня последняя версия xcode. Я в preferences->downloads установил шестую и пятую версию ios simalator.  Но когда я запуская приложение, у меня отображается только ios 6.1 simulator (слева вверху, рядом с кнопкой Run).
Как мне выбрать, чтобы приложение запускалось в ios 5 simulator?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках проекта есть опция Deployment Target, там выбирается минимальная версия iOS, на которой может устанавливаться приложение.
Видимо на данный момент у вас там установлено значение 6.1.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Спасибо большое.